# A query to get per month data for all months and calculate percentage per month per type

Tags: postgresql, count, window-functions, percentage, yearmonth

From the DB (Postgresql) I want to get the percentage per month (of all months) of stock items with a certain condition. So the total of the whole month is 100% and per condition it would be a percentage of that. I'm trying all kinds of 'partition by' queries, but i quite can't get it right.

In the example there would be an extra column and on each row there would be the percentage of that month. So the value for the new column for the first row it would be 25/506*100.

Right now I have and works is:

```
select to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM') as maand, count(si.id) as aantal,
case
    when condition_id=1 then 'Nieuw'
    when condition_id=2 then 'Als nieuw'
    when condition_id=3 then 'Goed'
    when condition_id=4 then 'Redelijk'
    when condition_id=5 then 'Matig'
    else 'Onbepaald'
end
from stock_items si
group by maand, condition_id
order by maand desc, condition_id asc
```

| maand | aantal | case | new column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | 25 | Nieuw | 25/506*100 |
| 2022-01 | 234 | Als nieuw | 234/506*100 |
| 2022-01 | 127 | Goed | 127/506*100 |
| 2022-01 | 16 | Redelijk | 16/506*100 |
| 2022-01 | 104 | Matig | 104/506*100 |
| 2021-12 | 456 | Nieuw | other month |

I hope it's all clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just warp it with CTE.

```
with a as (
    select to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM') as maand, count(si.id) as aantal,
    case
        when condition_id=1 then 'Nieuw'
        when condition_id=2 then 'Als nieuw'
        when condition_id=3 then 'Goed'
        when condition_id=4 then 'Redelijk'
        when condition_id=5 then 'Matig'
        else 'Onbepaald'
    end as case
    from stock_items si
    group by maand, condition_id
    order by maand desc, condition_id asc)
select a.*, aantal * 100 / sum(aantal) over (PARTITION BY maand)   as anntal_rate from a;
```

/* some characters so the edit is accepted */

Comment: Hi Mark!

Thanks for your answer. And sorry i got back to this only now. I had a couple of days off.

It says: Error (line 10) : column "aantal" does not exist.

I'm not sure how to get around that without subqueries if possible with subqueries.

Comment: @Sarnix updated answer. CTE just make things so easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got some reading to do, because i never heard of CTE.

Answer (score 0):

I got what I wanted. To realise i want it a little different, but this is the answer to my question.

```
select
    to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM') as maand, 
    count(id) as aantal,
    round((count(id) / (sum(count(id)) over (partition by to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM'))) * 100), 2) as percentage,
case
    when condition_id=1 then 'Nieuw'
    when condition_id=2 then 'Als nieuw'
    when condition_id=3 then 'Goed'
    when condition_id=4 then 'Redelijk'
    when condition_id=5 then 'Matig'
    else 'Onbepaald'
end
from stock_items
group by maand, condition_id
order by maand desc, condition_id asc
```